# Как передать переменную PHP в HTML документ

Tags: php, html, iis, denwer

Имеется HTML страница запущенная на IIS и PHP страница запущенная на Denwer

Можно ли передать переменную из php страницы в html документ, если они находятся в разных директориях? Пишу php код внутри html - не выполняется.

Comment: пример вашего кода в студию пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно ли передать переменную из php страницы в html документ, если они
>   находятся в разных директориях?

Вот простой пример как это можно сделать:

Имеется такая структура проекта:

```
/docroot
/someDir
--inc-file.php
index.php
```

Содержимое inc-file.php

```
<?php

define("HELLO_WORLD", "Hello world.");
```

Содержимое index.php:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/someDir/inc-file.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo HELLO_WORLD; // Там самая переменная HELLO_WORLD ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Если вы передаете переменную в файл с расширением `php`, то можно, но файл с другим расширением не будет знать, что делать с кодом-переменной из `php`.